# Local active directory access and management for development?

Tags: c#, active-directory, directoryentry

In an application we are developpment, we are accessing Active Directory users and groups using the .Net DirectoryEntry and DirectorySearcher classes. Managing the test groups and users during development is getting tedious.

I am wondering if there was an easy way to setup a simple local AD in which we could easily create / delete users and assign them or remove them from groups as we want with the DirectoryEntry / DirectorySearcher classes?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ADAM will allow you to install a local AD and run queries against it with the DirectoryServices namespace in .NET.

[Active Directory Application Mode (ADAM)](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=9688f8b9-1034-4ef6-a3e5-2a2a57b5c8e4&displaylang=en)

Only for your information, there is another AD related link that I find pretty interesting. I don't know if it's going to be useful for you, but has been for me, that is: [How to: (Almost) Everything in Active Directory](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/everythingInAD.aspx).